# How to indicate the a variable should be edited first

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have the following live template:

```
import {$NAME$} from "$PATH$";
$END$
```

When it's inserted into an editor, the order of inputting variables is defined as:

```
import {1} from "2";
```

Is there any way to change it to:

```
import {2} from "1";
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use **Edit variables** button when editing that Live Template and then use **Arrow Up** & **Arrow Down** buttons to rearrange them -- make `PATH` variable first in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you type the word that generates this code for example `import`, it puts the cursor at `{$NAME$}`, type `2`, then `TAB` and the cursor will start at `$PATH$` and type `1` Then `TAB` and finally type `?`

Comment: that basically just shows that I can use `TAB`, does it?

Comment: Yes that's it .